# Fullpage.js customization

Tags: javascript, slider, fullpage.js

I'm doing a project using fullpage.js and facing an issue of that. In my project I have vertical slides and in each vertical slides I have horizontal slides. When we use mouse to scroll the the slides are working fine. But when we use keyboard arrows it's confusing. ie, we need to use 'page up' and 'page down' arrows for vertical scroll and 'right' and 'left' arrows for horizontal scroll separately. Forcing clients to use separate arrows for different slides is my problem. Can we use only page up' and 'page down' arrows for both vertical slides and horizontal slides without breaking the continuity of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

Steps:

- Use the fullpage.js option `keyboardScrolling:false`
- Create your own keyboard bindings linking them to fullPage.js functions such as `moveTo`, `moveSectionUp`, `moveSlideRight` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But doing what you said is little confusing. Can you please describe whats your point?